# Java to click (with Robot) out of Frame

Tags: java, focus, frame

hope you guys are doing alright.
I've got a question to an Autoclicker. I've got a slider (JSlider, for choosing milliseconds) and 2 buttons (Start and Stop). Everything works so far, except for one thing: The click function doesn't work outside of my JFrame.

Here's my Start Button Listener:

```
buttonStart.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                buttonStop.setEnabled(true);
                buttonStart.setEnabled(false);
                slider.setEnabled(false);
                clickerActive = true;

                final Thread click = new Thread(new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        threadStarted = true;
                        while (clickerActive) {
                            try {
                                rbt.delay(slider.getValue());
                                rbt.mousePress(InputEvent.BUTTON1_DOWN_MASK);
                                rbt.mouseRelease(InputEvent.BUTTON1_DOWN_MASK);
                            } catch (final Exception e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                        threadStarted = false;
                    }

                });
                if (!threadStarted) {
                    click.start();
                }
            }
        });
```

And here's my Stop Button Listener:

```
buttonStop.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                buttonStop.setEnabled(false);
                buttonStart.setEnabled(true);
                slider.setEnabled(true);
                clickerActive = false;
            }
        });
```

Any ideas how to get it working, if the java window is not in focus?